# Open Explorer process with a search pattern on file name (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, search, explorer

Using VB.NET code, how can I open the Explorer process to search results based on criteria from a form? For example: form field A has the number "1" in it, and form field B has the date "2015-11-30" in it. By concatenating these two criteria in the VB code, I want to start the Explorer process and display all the file names within a given root folder that contains the pattern "1 2015-11-30". (Essentially, it would be the same results I would get typing the above into the Explorer Search box in Windows 7, except I need to code that.)

UPDATE Jan 25: I have come back to this last remaining issue after completing all other project coding and I am still having a problem in Windows 7 (works fine in Windows 10) after much research. Some additional helpful info I can offer this time is shown below. Note, I have also tried the AQS Search syntax using url encoding on the Crumb location and still get the same runtime error. Also note, I do NOT get a runtime error when I leave out the Crumb argument -- but that is of little practical use to me, just an observation.

Finally, I have also tried the code on other Win 7 machines at the corporate offices and get the same runtime error. Perhaps someone can try the code below snippet below on their Win 7 and advise what they get?

## IMPORTED ASSEMBLIES:

```
    Imports System
    Imports System.IO
    Imports System.Text
    Imports System.Drawing.Imaging
    Imports System.Threading
    Imports System.Configuration
    Imports System.Net.Mail
    Imports Microsoft.Win32
    Imports System.Web
    Imports System.ComponentModel
    Imports System.Windows
```

## SEARCH BUTTON CODE SNIPPET, INCLUDING MESSAGEBOX OUTPUT OF THE SEARCH STRING:

```
    Dim searchString As String
    Dim Search As String
    searchString = ControlChars.Quote & "     " & Me.DateTimePicker1.Value.Year.ToString & "-" & Me.DateTimePicker1.Value.Month.ToString().PadLeft(2, "0") & "-" & Me.DateTimePicker1.Value.Day.ToString().PadLeft(2, "0") & ControlChars.Quote
    Search = "search-ms:query=System.FileName:~=" & searchString.ToString & "&crumb=location:" & strArchiveDirectory_SHARED & ",recursive" & "&" 
    MessageBox.Show(Search) 'Messagebox shows: search-ms:query=System.FileName:~="     2016-01-25"&crumb=location:C:\EPS\Enforcement Photos Archive_DEMO,recursive&
    Process.Start(Search)
```

## RUNTIME ERROR:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception was unhandled
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  HResult=-2147467259
  Message=The system cannot find the file specified
  NativeErrorCode=2
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(String fileName)
   at EPS.Form1.btnSearch_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in E:\Code Development\Visual Studio 2013\EPS\EPS\Form1.vb:line 622
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.SendMessage(HandleRef hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SendMessage(Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ReflectMessageInternal(IntPtr hWnd, Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmCommand(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr wndProc, IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DefWndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.DefWndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
   at EPS.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 81
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

## A COUPLE OF WEB RESOURCE LINKS I REFERENCED OFTEN:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff684385.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144080(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: You might want to look into generating saved searches for Explorer and then launching them as a process, as suggested in this SuperUser answer: http://superuser.com/questions/499238/command-to-open-windows-explorer-window-with-filtered-results

Comment: Hi Adrian. Sorry for delayed response, and thank you for taking the time to reply. Unless I'm missing something about the Saved Search suggestion, I can't see how that would work, since the search criteria is determined by the user through the app UI.

Comment: You would take the input from your form and use it to generate the contents of a saved search file (the format of which can easily be discerned by generating a saved search with the type of criteria you're interested in and then saving it), and then execute that file. You can delete it afterwards if you wish.

Comment: I tried a compound manual Windows Search using **677888 AND *.jpg** and saved it to a **.search-ms** file. D-clicking executes the saved search. When I open it in Notepad I see a long XML parm set with a few spots that look like the search criteria. I gather I would use that XML code as my base and insert my variable criteria (ie: form txt box values) in place of the literal criteria and run it with my VB app. Assuming I'm on the right track, I have a 3 questions: Where can I find a definition for this complex XML format?; How do I insert the variables?; How do I execute this file from my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial & error I found a solution that allows my app's Search function to work in both Windows 7 and 10 (it crashed in 7).

The answer was that I had to manually URL-encode the Crumb Location using the string Replace method. The URLEncode method from HttpUtility did not encode the whole location string for reasons I still don't know.

My solution below:

```
    Dim urlEncodedLocationA As String = strArchiveDirectory_SHARED.Replace(":", "%3A")
    Dim urlEncodedLocationB As String = urlEncodedLocationA.Replace("\", "%5C")
    Dim urlEncodedLocationC As String = urlEncodedLocationB.Replace(" ", "%20")

    searchString = ControlChars.Quote & Me.txtBadgeNumber.Text & "     " & Me.DateTimePicker1.Value.Year.ToString & "-" & Me.DateTimePicker1.Value.Month.ToString().PadLeft(2, "0") & "-" & Me.DateTimePicker1.Value.Day.ToString().PadLeft(2, "0") & ControlChars.Quote
    Search = "search-ms:query=System.FileName:~<" & searchString.ToString & "&crumb=Location:" & urlEncodedLocationC & ",recursive" & "&" 'Search STARTS (~<) with the badge/date string.
    Process.Start(Search)
```

There may be a better way but this works for me.

Thank you to those who replied for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

try with this,

```
dim s as string= TextBox1.text & Textbox2.text
dim srch as string= "search-ms:query="& s &"&crumb=location:<Yourlocation>&"
Process.start(srch)
```

Hope this Will Be a Spark to your solution.Reference on more [CommandLine Options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff684385.aspx)

Comment: Akhil, you may be on to something. I get results when I just use Process.Start("search-ms:query=mystringhere"), however I get a "File not found runtime error when I include the Crumb argument. It appears the Location and Folder parameter are not supported post-XP (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb266520(v=vs.85).aspx). Is there another way to construct this protocol under Windows 7, or some other method you know of to accomplish my task? I appreciate you help.

Comment: Ok it must be something I'm doing wrong. I'll try again. Thank you.

Comment: Hello Akhil - Please see the Jan 25 Update in my original post above.